# How to change the last value in a pandas dataframe which conditioned out by loc?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to change the value of the last row of conditioned out by loc

I tried the following and it did not work...

```
df.loc({condition}, {column}).iloc[-1] = {some_value}
```

Answer (score 0):

Say I have this DF:

```
   Stake  Odds Ftr  Ind
0   0.25  2.50   H    1
1   0.15  4.00   D    2
2   0.26  1.75   A    2
3   0.30  2.20   H    1
4   0.10  1.85   H    3
5   0.40  3.20   A    3
6   0.32  1.50   D    3
7   0.11  1.20   H    1
8   0.20  2.15   H    2
9   0.25  1.65   A    2
```

When I run:

```
a = df[df['Ftr']=='H'].tail(1).index.values[0]
df.iloc[a,int(df.columns.get_indexer(['Odds']))] = 10
```

I get:

```
   Stake   Odds Ftr  Ind
0   0.25   2.50   H    1
1   0.15   4.00   D    2
2   0.26   1.75   A    2
3   0.30   2.20   H    1
4   0.10   1.85   H    3
5   0.40   3.20   A    3
6   0.32   1.50   D    3
7   0.11   1.20   H    1
8   0.20  10.00   H    2
9   0.25   1.65   A    2
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I would like to condition the dataframe first before getting the last row.

Comment: What would the condition be applied to?

Comment: The condition would be apply to the whole dataframe then single out a column. I think I was able to figure out by using df.at[--]. Just grabbing the index of the last row and change it that. I'm still curious on how you would do that without the index..

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but check my answer again and let me know